# OpportunityTeamMember - customization

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-teams

Is there a chance to modify links "Edit" and "Delete" in Opportunity Team Member Layout ? I mean whether we could remove eg "Delete" link ?

Because when I delete some user I can click "Undo" but when I click it I have a communicate like "Entity type is not undeletable" - how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, to achieve this you will need to create your own object which mimics the Opportunity team member behaviour.

Let's call Opportunity Team Manager. You can do all the customizations there and at the backend when a record inserted, deleted and undeleted in this object, you insert, delete and insert the Standard Opportunity team members.